# Reliable way to check if iOS is displaying a system alert over an app? (such as Location Services, etc.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Is there any way to check from a `UIViewController` whether or not the **Location Services** or **Contacts** permission prompts are visible over the application?

Comment: over other apps? erm I think that will be restricted by Sanboxing

Comment: What? ... No. Over the app in question (subject). Programmatically.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

The Method UIApplicationWillResignActive is triggered when a permissions prompt is triggered as you are describing. To listen for this, first add a listener to your controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self  selector:@selector(willResignActive) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Then, implement the selector you specified in the observer (willResignActive in this case)

```
- (void)willResignActive {
  //Location services or contacts permission prompts may have been shown
}
```

Please note, there is no guarantee that this was triggered because of the permissions prompts. It also could have been caused by an incoming phone call or text, a locked screen, pulling down notifications, etc. But if you know at what time your prompt should appear, you will have a good idea if it was shown or not.

Last thing, make sure you remove your observer in the dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't in general, because you should know when your application is authorized, and the prompt only shows up when you request that access. CoreLocation provides an API to get the current authorization state for your application, for example.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW72