# Swift - checking for system alert on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

If I present an AlertController using `self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` then I can also check if that alert is onscreen using `if self.presentedViewController == nil`

When it is an alert controller **presented by the system**,  `self.presentedViewController` is still nil even though there is an alert view on the screen.

Is there any way I can check for whether this alert is onscreen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reliable way to check if iOS is displaying a system alert over an app? (such as Location Services, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965982/reliable-way-to-check-if-ios-is-displaying-a-system-alert-over-an-app-such-as)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to see whether the app’s `keyWindow` is your window. If it isn’t, something is being presented in front of your app by the system.

Also look at your app’s state. If it isn’t active, it has been deactivated by something appearing front of it.

Comment: I have to rethink how I'm setting up my project here, but in general your answer was helpful in that using `if UIApplication.shared.keyWindow == self.view.window` does correctly show when the system alert is being presented in front of my app

Comment: @RanLearns, matt, sorry it doesn't work for me `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow == self.view.window` always return true...

Comment: @matt question is the same: How to detect system alert on the screen, moderators most likely will remove my question.

Comment: The best idea is to check `guard UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active else { return }`
Especially this is relevant in iOS 15 and up.